# Computer Click Event Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, events, random, click

How do I create a random click event driven by the computer? Where the user doesn't get to choose where it clicks?
I have created a table that is 5 buttons wide and 5 buttons tall, and created a click event where the user clicks on a button and the random number value is added onto their score.

```
Dim RandomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList()
Dim RandomNumber As New Random()
For Me.TableColunm = 0 To 4 Step 1
    For Me.TableRow = 0 To 4 Step 1
        Dim TemporaryNumber = RandomNumbers(RandomNumber.Next(0, RandomNumbers.Count))
        RandomNumbers.Remove(CInt(TemporaryNumber))
        TableButtons = New Button()
        With TableButtons
            .Name = "TextBox" & TableColunm.ToString & TableRow.ToString
            .Text = TemporaryNumber.ToString
            .Width = CInt(Me.Width / 4)
            .Left = CInt(TableColunm * (Me.Width / 4))
            .Top = TableRow * .Height
            '.Tag = TemporaryNumber
            AddHandler TableButtons.Click, AddressOf UserTableButtonClickEvent
        End With
        GameScreen.Controls.Add(TableButtons)
    Next TableRow
Next TableColunm
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.StackTrace & vbCrLf & "index1= " & TableColunm & vbCrLf & "index2= " & TableRow)
End Try


Private Sub UserTableButtonClickEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    CType(sender, Button).BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue
    OverAllScoreInteger += CInt(CType(sender, Button).Tag)
    GameScreen.UserScoreBox.Text = OverAllScoreInteger.ToString
    Dim TableButton As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    TableButton.Text = "#"
    TableButton.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

How do I make another event like this but at random?

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate all controls in the `GameScreen.Controls` collection and add them to a temporary list if they are a button. Then generate a random number in the range of the length of the list and click the button with this index:

```
Dim TempButtonList As New List(Of Button)
For Each c as Control in GameScreen.Controls
  If TypeOf(c) Is Button Then TempButtonList.Add(CType(c, Button))
Next
Dim Rnd as New Random
TempButtonList(rnd.Next(0, TempButtonList.Count-1)).PerformClick()
```

The `PerformClick()` method does exactly the same as if you would click that button with your mouse. The `If` in the loop makes sure you only add buttons in the controls collection, because there may of course be other controls inside.

**Complete example**

It's probably easier that way (Add a FlowLayoutPanel with Size=275; 275 and two Labels to a Form):

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Rnd As New Random
    For i = 1 To 25
        Dim b As New Button With {.Text = Rnd.Next(0, 100)}
        b.Width = 40
        b.Height = 40
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b)
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf b_hndl
    Next
End Sub
Private MyScore As Integer = 0
Private HisScore As Integer = 0
Dim Zug As Boolean = True
Private Sub b_hndl(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim ThisB As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Dim CurrScore As Integer = CInt(ThisB.Text)
    Dim CurrZug As Boolean = Zug
    Zug = Not Zug
    ThisB.Enabled = False
    ThisB.Text = "#"
    If CurrZug Then
        MyScore += CurrScore
        Label1.Text = MyScore.ToString
        ComputerMove()
    Else
        HisScore += CurrScore
        Label2.Text = HisScore.ToString
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub ComputerMove()
    Dim TempButtonList As New List(Of Button)
    For Each c As Control In FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls
        If TypeOf (c) Is Button Then
            Dim thisb As Button = CType(c, Button)
            If thisb.Enabled Then TempButtonList.Add(thisb)
        End If
    Next
    If TempButtonList.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Dim Rnd As New Random
    TempButtonList(Rnd.Next(0, TempButtonList.Count - 1)).PerformClick()
End Sub
End Class
```

The `Dim Zug As Boolean = True` determines if the player or the computer is currently in queue to select a button. It is switched on every button press, so the players take turns. The `ComputerMove` function is executed after the player clicked a button.

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working.... Do I need to add it into an Event Handler? Or where do I but it hah

Comment: You put it wherever you want to have the computer click a button. And again: "Doesn't work" is not a useful description of an error.

Comment: The form comes up blank with no cells / buttons to click for the game.

Comment: And would I create another sub called "ComputerTableButtonClickEvent" and copy the code you gave me into the sub or, into the 'With TableButtons' sections above?

Comment: See edit. As a general advice: Think about your game logic first: What shall happen at which point? Write it down, draw a flowchart. That way you get to the solution yourself much easier.